# Rebuild or Clean and Build?

Tags: c++, qt, c++17, qt-creator, qmake

On QtCreator, `Build` menu, I see

```
Rebuild Project
```

There are also

```
Clean Project
```

and

```
Build Project
```

I never know if I should `Clean Project` and `Buid Project` or just `Rebuild Project`, is there any difference?

(Personal opinion: If `Rebuild` does `Clean` and `Build` I would not mind if `Rebuild` is removed. I can do it quickly with a shortcut for each step)

Comment: It does what it tells you - Rebuild rebuilds the complete project, Clean cleans the project and Build builds it.

Answer (score 5):

> Rebuild Project, is there any difference?

yes, Rebuild is wrapping the `clean` and `build` for you in just one click.

Look in the "Compile output" of the QtCreator:

`Rebuild` Project does:

```
09:17:08: Starting: "/usr/bin/make" clean -j4
rm -f qrc_s.cpp
rm -f moc_predefs.h
rm -f moc_MainWindow.cpp
rm -f ui_MainWindow.h
rm -f main.o MainWindow.o qrc_s.o moc_MainWindow.o
rm -f *~ core *.core
```

and

```
09:17:08: Starting: "/usr/lib/qt5/bin/qmake" /home/me/test/test1/test1.pro -spec linux-g++ CONFIG+=debug CONFIG+=qml_debug
```

so "Rebuild" is calling `clean` and `build`

Comment: What is `clling`?

Comment: i meant calling... my typo